# How to not reload Google Maps everytime I switch to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a basic layout with a FragmentLayout inside it. I also have a navigation drawer and I change the contents of the FragmentLayout when different elements of the drawer are clicked, like so:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new WhateverFragment());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

One of the fragments I'm using has a MapView in it. I initialize the mapView on its onCreateView function, like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();//needed to get the map to display immediately
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return v;
    }
```

But this function gets called everytime I switch to this fragment, so the map gets reset and reloaded everytime (and thus not keeping markers or anything).

Where should I put this mapView initialization code so that it is not called everytime?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initialising your `MapView` from xml, consider creating it manually in code, and keeping a `WeakReference` to it in your fragment.

1. so you inflate your fragment's layout (without the MapView)
2. if your MapView field is null, initialise it with a new MapView
3. then add the MapView field as a child to the inflated xml.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I get the MapView from the WeakReference and call its onResume method: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.ad.z.o()' on a null object reference`

Comment: weakreference can point to null, so you need to check for null twice: (mMapView != null && mMapView.get() != null)

Answer (score 0):

hi you can initialize your map oncreate in fragment and then call like this

call **setRetainInstance(true)**

```
mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

**another solution,**

Call this when you start fragment,

```
 LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        Intent i = new Intent("TAG_REFRESH");
        lbm.sendBroadcast(i);
```

And your Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

MyReceiver r;
public void refresh() {
//yout code in refresh.
Log.i("Refresh", "YES");
}

public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(r);
}

public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
r = new MyReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(r,
        new IntentFilter("TAG_REFRESH"));
}

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyFragment.this.refresh();
}
}
```

hope this will help you